# How to justify paragraph to fill entire lines in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office

Currently i rewriting a PDF document to Word Document, but this specific formatting is something that i cannot reproduce. The right photo is the result that i'm looking for, while in the left is what i currently achieve. I want to fully justify the paragraph to fill each of its line.

To create that list, i use tab. It's just my working place standard.
[what i do vs the result that i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlKV7.png)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Just a note that this question is off-topic in this forum. This is a programming forum, not an application use forum. Better would have been the Super User Forum. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word ---- What is on topic here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i found the workaround (stupidly). I just use table to align it, the table itself use no border so it will be invisibe, and because i use table the Justify alignment is working as i expected now. Now i'm able to reproduce the second pic. Marking this as answered. [here is how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50lqJ.png)

Comment: Using Tables and Tabs to Organize Text in Word by Shauna Kelly, MVP.  http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/4UseTablesTabs.htm